# How do I add content (writings) to my website apart from my side navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a small website right now, but I have encountered this problem that is quite troublesome.

Ive successfully created a side navigation bar, following tips and tutorials, but am struggling in putting my content to the website. Every time I try it always ends up on the nav bar, so how do I add content out of/apart the nav bar? Another problem is that theres a white gap above everything, but that seems alright for now.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fa-times").click(function(){
  $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
  $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");
});

 $(".toggle_menu").click(function(){
  $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
  $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none; 
}

a { color: inherit; } 

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.toggle_menu{
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 margin-top: 70px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #648B79;
 z-index: 1000000;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.sidebar_menu{
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
 max-height: 100vh;
 background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
 opacity: 0.9;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times{
 right: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


.fa-times:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}

.boxed_item{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-weight:200;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border:solid 2px white;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.logo_title{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.navigation_selection{
 margin: 20px 0;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.navigation_item{
 font-weight: 200;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #D8D8D8;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.boxed_item_smaller{
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 width: 200px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-width: 1px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.boxed_item_smaller:hover{
 background-color: white;
 color: #111;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hide_menu{
 margin-left: -250px;
}

.opacity_one{
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.post-content {
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head> 
 <!--stylesheets-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <!--fonts-->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700,800,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <!--scripts-->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="menu.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6cde4f18cc.js"></script>
 <!--meta-->
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Slide-Out Navigation Bar</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i>
  
 <div class="sidebar_menu">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  <center>
   <a href="index.html"><h1 class="boxed_item">Cupcakery</h1></a>
   <h2 class="logo_title">The best cupcakes in town!</h2>
  </center>

  <ul class="navigation_selection">
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Cupcakes & Orders.html">Cupcakes & Orders</a></li>
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Who we are.html">Who we are</a></li> 
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Our Location.html">Our Location</a></li>
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <center>
   <a href="#"><h1 class="boxed item boxed_item_smaller">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   ORDER NOW!
   </h1></a>
  </center>
 <div class="post-body">
<section class="post-content">
<!--PROBLEM-->
<p>testing, why does this show up on the navbar?</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a closing "div" tag:

```css
* {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none; 
}

a { color: inherit; } 

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.toggle_menu{
 position: fixed;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 margin-top: 70px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #648B79;
 z-index: 1000000;
 font-size: 2em;
}

.sidebar_menu{
 position: fixed;
 width: 250px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100vh;
 max-height: 100vh;
 background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
 opacity: 0.9;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-times{
 right: 10px;
 top: 10px;
 opacity: 0.7;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


.fa-times:hover{
 opacity: 1;
}

.boxed_item{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-weight:200;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 border:solid 2px white;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 70px;
}

.logo_title{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.navigation_selection{
 margin: 20px 0;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

.navigation_item{
 font-weight: 200;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #D8D8D8;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.boxed_item_smaller{
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #D8D8D8;
 width: 200px;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-width: 1px;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.boxed_item_smaller:hover{
 background-color: white;
 color: #111;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.hide_menu{
 margin-left: -250px;
}

.opacity_one{
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.post-body {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
}

.post-content {
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="menu.js"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6cde4f18cc.js"></script>



 <i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i> 
 <div class="sidebar_menu">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  <center>
   <a href="index.html"><h1 class="boxed_item">Cupcakery</h1></a>
   <h2 class="logo_title">The best cupcakes in town!</h2>
  </center>

  <ul class="navigation_selection">
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Cupcakes & Orders.html">Cupcakes & Orders</a></li>
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Who we are.html">Who we are</a></li> 
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Our Location.html">Our Location</a></li>
   <li class="navigation_item"><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <center>
   <a href="#"><h1 class="boxed item boxed_item_smaller">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   ORDER NOW!
   </h1></a>
  </center>
   </div> <!--closing sidebar_menu div -->
 <div class="post-body">
<section class="post-content">
<!--PROBLEM-->
<p>testing, why does this show up on the navbar?</p>
```

If you add the closing tag right before your "post-body" div, it should adjust and not show in your nav menu.